# Embedded Ruby: Array.each "No method" error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

In my helper I produce a Hash from a database. The Hash contains a key for each state, with a value containing an array of cities. Each city entry is itself an array, with name and an id.

For example (this code is just an illustration):

```
myHash[key => MD, value=>[ ['Annapolis',1],['Potomac',2] ] ]
```

This is the actual code to produce the Hash:

```
def get_city_hash
  stateHash = Hash.new
  City.all.each do |c|
    if !stateHash.include? c.stateab
      stateHash[c.stateab] = Array.new
    end
    stateHash[c.stateab] << [c.name, c.id]
  end
end
```

The problem is when I try to make a corresonding Associative Array in javascript, it seems my Array object for each city has no .each method (took out code in middle for less clutter)

```
  var city_array = [
  <% get_city_hash.each do |key, value|%>
    <%value.each do |v|%>
    <%end%>
 <%end%>
```

For this code I get this error on the line containing value.each:

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

I tested a .each on the state Arrays in the helper and it worked fine. What changes in this format that I get a NilClass?

Comment: Can you confirm that the get_city_hash indeed returns stateHash (it looks like it should, but you can add an additional stateHash after the closing end of the City.all loop just to be absolutely sure!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

#### Problem #1

Your `get_city_hash` method doesn't return `cityHash`, it returns the result of `each`, which will be the Enumerable you called it on (i.e. the result of `City.all`). That's not a Hash, so when you call `each` on it only one argument is passed into the block and the second argument, `c`, is always `nil`.

On top of that, there's a lot of room for improvement in that method. First, instead of the `if !stateHash.include?` business, just give your Hash a default value:

```
def get_city_hash
  state_hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }

  City.select(:id, :stateab, :name).all.each do |c|
    state_hash[c.stateab] << [c.name, c.id]
  end

  state_hash
end
```

I've also added `select` since you should never retrieve columns from the database that you're not going to use.

But we can clean this up more using `each_with_object`:

```ruby
def get_city_hash
  city_hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }

  City.select(:id, :stateab, :name).all
    .each_with_object(Hash.new([])) do |city, city_hash|
      city_hash[city.stateab] << city.values_at(:name, :id)
    end
end
```

Or we can do this, which may be a bit too "clever" but which I'm nevertheless quite partial to.

```ruby
def get_city_hash
  City.all.pluck(:stateab, :name, :id)
    .group_by(&:shift)
end
```

#### Problem #2

In your view you're trying to generate JavaScript code, which is never a good idea. You should always, always let Rails generate valid JSON for you:

```ruby
var cities = <%= raw get_city_hash.to_json %>;
```

Comment: With problem #2 I'm quite partial to using [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) to pass things from rails controllers to javascript in views.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. But could you perhaps provide more explanation for the second two solutions to the first problem? The structure is a little unfamiliar to me, just started with rails a few weeks ago and am happy to expand my arsenal.

Comment: I tried some of your solutions. I sill appreciate your answer, but perhaps you overlooked that I'm inserting the values into arrays in the city_hash method, so I need an if statement to check if one already exists. I tried the code you posted and it didn't work. Also, the to_json suggestion gave me some strange garbled ruby stuff in my javascript. Is it possible you left out a part of the code?

Comment: I've edited my answer to use the default proc correctly (`Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }` instead of `Hash.new([])`). I can't diagnose "strange garbled Ruby stuff" without seeing it. You may have to use the `raw` method to prevent Rails from escaping the JSON. I've edited my answer to include this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you define a helper method named as "get_city_hash" and you called in view "get_city_array". Change "get_city_array" to "get_city_hash"

Comment: sorry, that's a typo in the question. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 <% get_city_hash.each do |key, value|%>
    <% unless value.blank? %>
     <%value.each do |v|%>

     <%end%>
    <% end%>
 <%end%>
```

or you can try to remove `nil` value from the hash `value` using `compact` `get_city_hash.compact.each`

The rails 4.1 `compact` read: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-compact

```
     <% get_city_hash.compact.each do |key, value|%>
     <%value.each do |v|%>

     <%end%>
   <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

This teaches us the lesson of relying on Ruby's super concise formulations...

My helper method was returning some index value, not the actual hash I was making!

Comment: See my answer for an explanation. It doesn't have to do with Ruby's brevity, but rather the fact that Enumerable#each returns its callee.